# spring cloud gateway 2 add Authentication info header

Tags: project-reactor, spring-cloud-gateway

I need add some user info which get from `exchange.getPrincipal()` to the forward request, and write a `GlobalFilter` like below:

```
public class UserInfoFilter implements GlobalFilter, Ordered {

@Override
public int getOrder() {
    return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
}

@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
    ServerHttpRequest.Builder mutate = exchange.getRequest().mutate();
    return exchange.getPrincipal().map(principal -> {
        if (principal instanceof Authentication) {
            Authentication authentication = (Authentication) principal;
            Object principal1 = authentication.getPrincipal();
            if (principal1 instanceof UserDetails) {
                UserDetails user = (UserDetails) principal1;
                mutate.header("userName", user.getUsername());
            }
        }
        return mutate;
    }).doOnSuccess(builder -> chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(builder.build()).build())).then();
}
```

}

but when I enable this filter, I will get nothing response just a 200 status code without any exception throw. I guess I use the wrong way of reactor, and I had try a lot but can't get it work.

Comment: change `doOnSuccess()` to `flatMap()` and remove  the last `then()` make it work.